# Content slider with 3 slides

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, slide

I'm creating a custom content slider using jQuery. Please see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/isuru_nan/BwD6f/3/) for a working example. In this example, I have only 2 slides. When clicked upon the green button the slides to the next one.

I want to add more slides to this and have the button click to slide to each of them (no previous button). The current jQuery function has the `id` of the next div hard-coded. Now when I add more slides, this method won't be effective. I don't know how to write one function to say, detect the current div you're in and when clicked next, go to the next one. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

I have posted the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-slider-space">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">

        <div id="slide1" class="main-slide">

        </div><!-- end of slide1 -->   

        <div id="slide2" class="main-slide">

        </div><!-- end of slide2 -->   

    </div> <!-- end of slider-wrapper -->   
</div><!-- end of main-slider-space -->

<div id="main-slider-next" class="slider-buttons"><a class="active" href="#"></a></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-slider-space {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#C36;
    margin-left:50px;
}

.slider-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    width:3000px;
    height:100%;
}

.main-slide {
    width:600px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

#slide1 { background-color:#5FF; }
#slide2 { background-color:#F5F; }

.slider-buttons {
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}

.slider-buttons:hover { cursor:pointer; }

#main-slider-next {
    background-color:#99CC66;
    right:30px;
    top:50%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function goto(id, t){
    $(".slider-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#main-slider-next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        goto('#slide2', this);
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/isuru_nan/BwD6f/3/)

Comment: May I ask why you're reinventing the wheel? There are a zillion jQuery sliders available for free, and they should handle your situation just fine. 

The solution is to either add classes to the currently selected element to keep track of it, or to put the elements in an array and track them that way, by index. I'm not inclined to re-write what's been done so many times before, however.

Comment: @isherwood The ones I came across didn't really offer the customization capabilities I need. If you know of a few plugins which would suit this, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Most of them allow you to slide any child element (div, list, etc.) and also allow you to assign your own elements as controls. What custom features have you found missing?

Comment: Most of the plugins I came across aren't actually content sliders but  image sliders.

Comment: And others have only tabbed navigation. Not the arrows.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you. This looks promising. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with css for animations, here is what I changed in yours :

```
.main-slide {
    position:absolute;
    width:600px;
    height:100%;

    -webkit-transition:left 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition:left 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition:left 0.5s linear;
    transition:left 0.5s linear;
}

.main-slide:not(.current){
    left:600px;
}

.main-slide.current{
    left:0px;
}
```

Then in your click handler simply change the class of the current element :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#main-slider-next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        next();
        return false;
    }); 
});

function next(){
    var cur = $(".slider-wrapper").children(".current");
    var next = cur.next(".main-slide");
    if(next.length) {
        cur.removeClass("current");
        next.addClass("current");
    }
}
```

Here is a fiddle with what I've done http://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/rhXZT/1/

If you would like to keep the previous slide in sight, just remove the line :

```
cur.removeClass("current");
```